# python - ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'pyproj.crs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinates

I tried to import pyproj, and this error occurred.

```
import pyproj
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-98cb605ea9de>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyproj

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from pyproj.crs import CRS

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj.crs'
```

At first, I thought it has problem with pyproj, but after I reinstalled the latest version of pyproj,

this error still occurred. I also tried to import cartopy.crs and same problem happened.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-139fa5ad2567>", line 1, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cartopy.crs'
```

How can I do with this problem? Is there a *set* *of* *coordinate* *reference* *system* that I can download

somewhere, or should I remove all about my python and reinstall? I'm really hoping to avoid that.

Any advice, please!

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. It appears that you are running these in iPython, how are you launching the instance of ipython? How did you install these modules? Are you sure the module was installed to the same instance of python you are using for iPython ? (ie using `pip3` vs `pip`)

Comment: I used spyder 3.3.1, and I installed it from anaconda prompt, using conda install !

Comment: Hmmmm... that seems like that should work but I don't have a lot of experience with Anaconda on Windows...

You mentioned the option of using a different coordinate library, I typically use pymap3d. https://github.com/scivision/pymap3d . Perhaps you will have better luck with that?

Answer (score 0):

What finally helped me was

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

the _crs module is a pyx file (needs to be translated to C by Cython), pyximport allows it to be imported.